# How to change date field label?

Tags: theming, datetime, entities

In my content I have one date field label, it is showing all uppercase letters automatically.

*Example* :I have given date field label as *birthday(lower case)* but it's automatically showing *BIRTHDAY(UPPERCASE)*. How can I overcome this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Theme are you using? And what happens if you (temporary) switch to some other theme, eg one of the core themes?

Comment: @ Pierre.vriens - thanks for your response,i am using danland theme,and it is not temporary what i am doing.

Comment: The label your trying to modify comes under **fieldset** element. You are applying css property on wrong element.

Comment: @ WaQaR Ali - Thanks for your response,Then what can i change,how can i over come this.

Answer (score 1):

use Css if nothing is working to show the label in small letters.

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

Comment: Comments have been removed; please don't use them for extended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding you have applied CSS on wrong element, Please apply "text-transform: lowercase" on "label".

```
.from-type-textfield label {
           text-transform: lowercase
     }
```

Please put it on your `.css` file it will work fine.

Comment: @ skv - Thanks  for your response,from-type-textfield label { text-transform: lowercase } element is not there in my css file.

Comment: According to the Screen shot(Inspect Element) you provided initially there is  <div class="from-type-textfield label..."> above date label, so take that class and put the

 .from-type-textfield label {
           text-transform: lowercase
     }

as it is on your css file...
it will work

Comment: @SujeetKumarVerma you are applying css on wrong element. **.from-type-textfield label** is the class of simple textfield but the **label** of datefield as shown in above image comes under **fieldset**.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying date field label is showing all uppercase letters automatically there might be the case of bad cache. to get rid of it do the following steps:

If you are working with command line try to clear the drupal cache by writing the command as:

```
 `drush cc all`
```

If you are not using the command line then go in the Administer Settings: **Configuration>>Development>> Performance** or **admin/config/development/performance** and click on clear all cache. It should work fine.

and if not worked this too then apply the CSS code in the style.css file inside your theme folder for that particular element

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

Comment: @ rfegade - Thanks for your response,how can i find date field element in css.

Comment: which browser are you using? if you are using firefox then install the add on named fire bug and then press F12  when you are on your website and inspect the particular all capital label of date field and check the class which is applied to it this all info is shown at the bottom when you start your fire bug tool, there you can edit the css also to alter the values. thanks